# no lwjgl in java.library.path - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

Im currently using LWJGL 2.9.1 and im getting this error.
I've included the libraries and natives in the netbeans library manager.

The jars and dll's are stored

> "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LWJGLTest\lib\natives"
>
> "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LWJGLTest\lib\jars"

I've went into the VM Options and added this line as instructed on other Q&As but still no help :(

> Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Tom\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LWJGLTest\lib\natives"

I've also tried without the quotation marks

> Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Tom\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LWJGLTest\lib\natives

Comment: Got it working now, moved the native files into another subfolder called "win" and changed the VM options accordingly and it worked

-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Tom\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LWJGLTest\lib\natives\win"

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and close your own question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to rmail2006's comment, I've made it works following these steps:

Go to project properties -> Run, and edit "VM Options":

```
-Djava.library.path="/path/to/your/lwjgl/lib/natives/macosx"
```